# What is the connection element between meet of a subset and join of a poset?

Tags: order-theory

> In a preordered set or partially ordered set then the ***meet*** or infimum of a subset of elements is, if it exists, the largest element which is smaller or equal to all the elements in the set
>
> If $x$ and $y$ are elements of a poset, then their ***join***, or supremum, is an element $x \vee y $ of the poset such that...

I would like to know the element in common that can 'connect' a meet of a subset with a join of a poset

Comment: What do you mean with "connect"?

Comment: See [Join and meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I read *Join and meet are symmetric duals with respect to order inversion* - what does it mean when it says "with respect to order inversion" ? From where come from that 'order inversion', what does it mean?

Comment: It means that if you swap from the relation *subset* ($\subseteq$) to *superset* ($\supseteq$) you have to exchange join and meet.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - mm.. I read [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superset.html) that  *If B is a subset of A, then A is a superset of B* but preliminar condition to have a superset is have a sort of 'superposition' between elements of A and B? I read *a set A is a subset of a set B, or equivalently B is a superset of A, if A is "contained" inside B, that is, all elements of A are also elements of B. A and B may coincide* - How is possible *to super-position-ing* ?

Comment: Consider a simple example : natural numbers with $\le$. The *join* (supremum) of $3$ and $5$ is $5$ and the *meet* (infimum) of $3$ and $5$ is $3$. What happens if we swap from $\le$ to $\ge$ ?

Comment: The join of 3 and 5 become 3 and the meet of 3 and 5 become 5? If is so..why do this thing, for what purpose ?